# Erro relacionado à Prolog numa página .xhtml utilizando o NetBeans

Tags: xhtml, prolog

Existe alguma relação entre páginas .xhtml e prolog? Ou a compilação de páginas e prolog em NetBeans?

Usando o NetBeans me aparece um erro de compilação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo perceber a ligação entre uma coisa  (.xhtml, JSF) e Prolog. Será que o IDE utiliza prolog em algum momento?

**Nota:** Já removi o "q" e tudo funciona, mas ainda não percebi a relação com Prolog.

Comment: Nunca foi tão difícil fazer uma pergunta, e colocar as tags. Coloquei várias que podem estar relacionadas.

Comment: Porque aquele 'q' está na primeira linha?

Comment: Foi um erro da natureza que me levou a ter esta dúvida. Escrevi sem querer @Rafael

Comment: Resolveu o problema?

Comment: @Rafa o problema não é este (vide minha questão), mas sim o que isso tem que ver com prolog? Percebes.

Comment: Sim, provavelmente é alguma palavra reservada ao Prolog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro não está falando da linguagem Prolog, e sim do [*prólogo* XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms256037(v=vs.100).aspx), que é aquele trecho em que você declara que o documento está em XML, antes do nó raiz e do conteúdo em si.

Comment: k^10000, não consigo parar de rir de mim mesmo. Obrigado @bfavaretto. Um acento não faria mal (kkkk)